# Formatting wildcard in ms access query on a datefield

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access, string.format

I have a datefield `DTB_VER.VER_DATUM` in my MS Access database with all full dates (e.g. 03-04-2012).

When I create the following query with a string format(vb.net):

```
Dim sql as string =  string.format("SELECT * FROM DTB_VER WHERE VER_DATUM LIKE '{0}%-{1}%-{2}%'", day, month, year)
```

With this query I can search perfectly for a day or a year or a combination of the two, but as soon as I enter a month it fails, and I can't figure out why.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM DTB_VER where Day(Ver_datum) like '*day*' and Month(Ver_datum) like '*month*' and year(Ver_datum) like '*year*'
```

And again I can search on day or year or a combination of the two (and leave month blank) but I can't search for a month.

Comment: What is the day, month, year order for your locale?

Comment: VER_DATUM is a Date/Time field in access db?

Comment: dd-MM-yyyy is the order i use.

Comment: no wait, i just double checked it, it is a datefield, with the format set to (dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: When you say the format is set, do you mean that the format property is set? This can mask problems. The format should come from the locale.

Comment: MS Access works with external queries where the date format is American or unambiguous (yyyy-mm-dd, yyyy/mm/dd are good) however, you are forcing a string comparison with Like and quotes, so all bets are off. Testing on my own PC (locale dd/mm/yyyy) with a field formatted to yyyy/mm/dd, I find that `SELECT t.ADate FROM Table1 t WHERE t.ADate Like '04/03/2013'` works to return 4th March, in spite of the field format.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Access date format for example

```
sql="SELECT * FROM DTB_VER WHERE VER_DATUM=#" & year & "/" & month & "-/" & day & "#"
```

You can not use LIKE with dates. If you want to select all the days in a month you need something like :-

```
sql="SELECT * FROM DTB_VER WHERE VER_DATUM>=#" & year & "-" & month & "-01# and VER_DATUM<#" & format(dateadd("m",1,cdate(year & "/" month & "/" & day),"yyyy/mm") & "/01"
```

Comment: As it so happens, you can use Like, which is surprising. I tried a mock up in Access with an ADO connection, and it worked, as you can see from my comments on the OP.

Comment: Heey richard, thank you for your answer, but i'm looking for a way to use wildcards (e.g. search for a day or a month or a year or a combination of those three.)

Comment: Be careful with using wildcards in dates. If you ever port the data part of an Access application to another database you may find that it does not support wildcards.